# Ctrl+Alt+Arrow up/down LIbreOffice Writer vs Workspace

Tags: libreoffice, workspaces

I often use Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Up/Down to reorder paragraphs in MS Word and LibreOffice Writer and also in text editors that allow it.

When I work in Ubuntu this key moves the screen-focus between Workspaces and has no effect on my text and I wonder if someone has found a workaround or if I'm stuck with this behaviour?

Comment: I discovered a simple solution in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941304/disabling-keyboard-shortcuts-didnt-work-in-ubuntu
Open Ubuntu Settings - find Keyboard Shortcuts - re-set Ctrl+PgUp/PgDown and everything works fine.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below by clicking the '*Answer your question*' button and add the link as the reference. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keybinding and use the alternative keybinding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> (or define your own) to switch workspaces. That way, the keybindings are not anymore intercepted by the Shell, and will work in Libreoffice.

You can use dconf-editor (not installed by default) to change the keybindings using a graphical tool, but it is much faster and more precise to change the keybindings using commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Super>Page_Down']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down']
```

This removes all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> combinations for switching workspace and moving windows between workspaces, leaving only <kbd>Super</kbd> combinations.

To undo, i.e., reset to default, use `reset` in the commands above and leave out the key definition.